# Wrap text between two asterisks in HTML *bold*

Tags: c#

What I want to do is take a string like the following

```
 This is my string and *this text* should be wrapped with <strong></strong>
```

The result should be

This is my string and **this text** should be wrapped with

Comment: I am confused.  Why are you trying to do this in C#?

Comment: [`\*[\w\s]+?\*`](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C*%5B%5Cw%5Cs%5D%2B%3F%5C*&input=This%20is%20my%20string%20and%20*this%20text*%20should%20be%20wrapped%20with%20%3Cstrong%3E%3C%2Fstrong%3E) seems reasonable.

Comment: This is a very odd question, but yes. A Regex replace solution, like @MartyWallace mentions would be the most reliable and elegant.

Comment: If doing this in C# is a bad idea please let me know why. I'm doing it in an asp.net website.

Comment: @BLaZuRE how does it matter? Seems like a perfectly valid thing to want to do.

Comment: @Sprague Because there was no mention of .NET (which I'm inexperienced with) and it appears the intent is to interpret it in a web browser.  My first instinct was to wonder why it wasn't being done in PHP or ASP.NET.  Then I did a little more research into C# with .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work pretty well:

```
var str = "This is my string and *this text* should be wrapped with";

var updatedstr = String.Concat(
          Regex.Split(str, @"\*")
          .Select((p, i) => i % 2 == 0 ?  p : 
               string.Concat("<strong>", p, "</strong>"))
          .ToArray()
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
string s = "This is my string and *this text* should be wrapped with <strong></strong>";
int i = 0;
while (s.IndexOf('*') > -1)
{
    string tag = i % 0 == 0 ? "<strong>" : "</strong>";
    s = s.Substring(0, s.indexOf('*')) + tag + s.Substring(s.indexOf('*')+1);
    ++i;
}
```

Or Marty Wallace's regex idea in the comments on the question, `\*[^*]+?\*`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very simple regex for this case:

```cs
var text = "";
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\*([^*]*)\*", "<b>$1</b>");
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C*%28%5B%5E*%5D*%29%5C*&i=This%20is%20my%20string%20and%20*this%20text*%20should%20be%20wrapped%20with%20%3Cstrong%3E%3C%2Fstrong%3E&r=%3Cb%3E%241%3C%2Fb%3E). Here, `\*([^*]*)\` matches

- `\*` - a literal asterisk (`*` is a special regex metacharacter and needs escaping in the literal meaning)
- `([^*]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than a `*` char
- `\*` - a `*` char.

The `$1` in the replacement pattern refers to the value captured in Group 2.

*Demo screen*:

[image]